# Printed Validation errors of wtforms suddenly stopped after css applied to jinja template

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I have a Flask-WTForm that has a few validation checks. I've been playing around with css and all of a sudden the validation errors are no longer printing on the screen. The validation seems to be still happening as the screen get's stuck and doesn't return the following page so I presume the validation is still taking place- just not printing the messages. Here is the template I have been working on (this is the only file I've made changed to so I presume the problem lies here):

```
<!-- extend base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<center>



<form method="GET" name="results">
 {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

<table>
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <tr>
                <th>RAI Number</th>
        </tr>


        <tr>
                <td> {{ form.rai_number(value=rai_number, readonly=true) }} </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
                <th>New Asset ID</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td> {{ form.fabric_spool_number }} </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table border=0 >
        {% for error in form.fabric_spool_number.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
<br>
<br>



<br>
<br>
<br>


<table>
<tr><td>{{ form.username.label }}</td> <td>{{ form.username }} </td>
</tr>
</table>
{% for error in form.username.errors %}
 <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
{% endfor %}
<br>
<br>
<table>

<tr>
        <td> {{ form.carrier_format.label }} </td> <td> {{ form.carrier_format }} </td>
         <td> {{ form.physical_location.label }} </td> <td> {{ form.physical_location }} </td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td width=300px />
        </td>
        <td> {% for error in form.carrier_format.errors %}
<span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
{% endfor %} 
        </td>
        <td width=300px />
        </td>
        <td> {% for error in form.physical_location.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
         {% endfor %}
        </td>
</tr>

<tr>
         <td> {{ form.programme_sub_category.label }} </td> <td> {{ form.programme_sub_category }} </td>
         <td> {{ form.programme_category.label }} </td> <td> {{ form.programme_category }} </td>
</tr>
<tr>
          <td width=300px />

         </td>
         <td> {% for error in form.programme_sub_category.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
         {% endfor %}
        </td>
</tr>


</table>


    {{ form.brand_title.label }}
    {{ form.brand_title(value=brand_title) }}

    {{ form.recording_artist.label }}
    {{ form.recording_artist(value=recording_artist) }}

    {{ form.producer.label }}
    {{ form.producer(value=producer) }}

    {{ form.session.label }}
    {{ form.session(value=session) }}

    {{ form.tx_date.label }}
    {{ form.tx_date(value=tx_date) }}

<p> {% for error in form.tx_date.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
         {% endfor %} </p>

    {{ form.network.label }}
    {{ form.network(value=network) }}

<p> {% for error in form.network.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
         {% endfor %} </p>
    {{ form.programme_number.label }}
    {{ form.programme_number(value=programme_number) }}

<p> {% for error in form.programme_number.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
         {% endfor %} </p>

    {{ form.start_time_1.label }}
    {{ form.start_time_1(value=start_time_1) }}

<p> {% for error in form.start_time_1.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
         {% endfor %} </p>
    {{ form.end_time_1.label }}
    {{ form.end_time_1(value=end_time_1) }}

<p> {% for error in form.end_time_1.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
         {% endfor %} </p>
    {{ form.start_time_2.label }}
    {{ form.start_time_2(value=start_time_2) }}

<p> {% for error in form.start_time_2.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
         {% endfor %} </p>
    {{ form.end_time_2.label }}
    {{ form.end_time_2(value=end_time_2) }}

<p> {% for error in form.end_time_2.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
         {% endfor %} </p>
    {{ form.duration.label }}

    {{ form.duration(value=duration) }}

<p> {% for error in form.duration.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
         {% endfor %} </p>
    {{ form.part_number.label }}
    {{ form.part_number(value=part_number) }}

<p> {% for error in form.part_number.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
         {% endfor %} </p>
    {{ form.number_of_parts.label }}
    {{ form.number_of_parts(value=number_of_parts) }}

<p> {% for error in form.number_of_parts.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
         {% endfor %} </p>
    {{ form.disc_number.label }}
    {{ form.disc_number(value=disc_number) }}

<p> {% for error in form.disc_number.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
         {% endfor %} </p>
    {{ form.number_of_discs.label }}
    {{ form.number_of_discs(value=number_of_discs) }}

<p> {% for error in form.number_of_discs.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
         {% endfor %} </p>
    {{ form.additional_info.label }}
    {{ form.additional_info(value=additional_info) }}

<p> {% for error in form.additional_info.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;"> [{{ error }} ]</span>
         {% endfor %} </p>

    {{ form.notes.label }}
    {{ form.notes(value=notes) }}
<p><input type="submit" value="Confirm"></p>

  </form>

{% endblock %}
```